# Does the C++ Object not get std::moved?

Tags: c++, c++14, move

I got the following code: ([Code Live: C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh/6ypjp))

```
class Worker
{
public:
  Worker (std::string name):_name (name) {};

  Worker (const Worker & worker):_name (worker._name)
  {  std::cout << _name << " got copied!" << std::endl; }

  Worker (Worker && other):_name (other._name)
  {  std::cout << _name << " got moved!" << std::endl;  }

  ~Worker ()
  {  std::cout << _name << " got destroyed!" << std::endl;  }

  void changeName(std::string name)
  {  this->_name = name;  }

private:
  std::string _name;
};

class Factory
{
public:
  Factory ()
  {  std::cout << "Factory got created!" << std::endl;  }

   ~Factory ()
  {  std::cout << "Factory got destroyed!" << std::endl;  }

  void addWorker (Worker & worker)
  {  this->workers.push_back (std::move (worker));  }

  Worker & getLastWorker ()
  {  this->workers.back ();  }

private:
  std::vector < Worker > workers;
};
```

```
int main ()
{
  auto factory = std::make_unique < Factory > ();
  Worker w1 ("Bob");
  factory->addWorker (w1);
  Worker & workerRef = factory->getLastWorker ();
  //workerRef.changeName("Mary");

  return 0;
}
```

Where I have a `Factory` storing at its `Workers` in a vector. When I run the `main()` I get the following output:

```
Factory got created!
Bob got moved!
Bob got destroyed!
Factory got destroyed!
Bob got destroyed!
```

But I can't get my head around why `Bob got destroyed!` appears two times, as I thought `Worker w1` gets moved to the vector `workers` in the `Factory`. Additionally, if you comment in `workerRef.changeName("Mary");` the code crashes with `Segmentation fault`.

I'm coding with c++ for a month now and really struggle here. I have googled quite for a while, but can't find a hint, so any help is great!

Comment: Taking an rvalue reference to something that you then move from feels like a very surprising interface. Is there a reason for this choice?

Comment: I watched https://youtu.be/cO1lb2MiDr8?t=30m46s where he suggested to std::move in std::vector in a push_back(). Thats the only reason I tried it that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moving only moves the contents of objects (if implemented like that, it could just copy). It doesn't mean the original object vanishes, only that its value possibly changes.

Your example creates **two** objects in two places:

1. `Worker w1 ("Bob");`
2. `this->workers.push_back (std::move (worker));`

The second steals the guts from the first (on the face of it, anyway), but the first is still alive. And any living object will have its destructor called at the end of its lifetime (for `w1` it's the closing of `main`).

Comment: Is there a way to make the original object vanish. I mean is there a way to implement the move constructor here, so that it actually moves.

Comment: @GauravSehgal - No. An object is a region of storage that has some value. A programmer can change the value, but the region of storage will stay an object until a destructor will be called. There is no getting around it.

Comment: @GauravSehgal - The  destructor for a moved-from string will likely just test if a pointer is null, and then do nothing.

Comment: @GauravSehgal: There are ways to prevent the destructor call (e.g. just not calling it after using placement new to create the object), but this is usually a really bad idea if the object is not a POD rsp. trivially destructible. I certainly wouldn't recommend it for any object that uses ``std::allocator``, such as ``std::string``. There are legitimate uses of this for containers that use stateful ("pool" or "arena") allocators, in short when the parent object dies you can improve performance by deallocating the whole arena in one go.

Comment: @StoryTeller: It's worth mentioning here (once more :-) ) that ``std::string{"Bob"}``, especially in C++11, might use small string optimization, so there's no point clearing it on move.

Comment: @ArneVogel - Wasn't it the C++11 change in specification that precluded SSO?

Comment: @StoryTeller: No, the C++11 change precludes COW (copy on write), which e.g. GCC used in its now obsolete ABI. The main reason is that it is considered a "pessimization" in multi-threaded programs. SSO is the "wanted" optimization.

Answer (score 5):

You still have two objects, one in `main` and one inside the vector.

"Moving" doesn't actually move an object, only its contents - at least conceptually (`std::move` is only a type cast).
It's not necessarily the case that anything moves at all, like in your case, where the "move constructor" behaves exactly like a copy constructor.

If you want a more "move-y" move constructor, you should write  `:_name (std::move(other._name))`, which will make `w1`'s name empty.

The reason for the crash is that you forgot to write `return` in `getLastWorker`.
Increase the warning level on your compiler and pay attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your move-constructor doesn't really *move* anything, it just copies the string.

And as you push back the `Worker` into the vector you still have two `Worker` objects: One in the `main` function and one inside the vector. Both of these objects needs to be destructed.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

An empty object destructor is also called.

In `move constractor` the old object transfers its content (especially pointers) to the new one, and become empty, then it been destroyed at the end of scope as an empty object.

Take a notice that after the move constructor the original shouldn't have called Bob anymore...